# Custom widget not duplicating children drawable state

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a custom widget which is basically an EditText which has a small 'clear' button to the right, which cleans the edittext.
I built it as a subclass of LinearLayout, which adds the EditText and the Button in the constructor.
Everything works the way it should, except that I want the whole LinearLayout to have a Focused style when the EditText has focus; I want the user to see it as an EditText, not as a container with an EditText.

I attempted using addStatesFromChildren, but it does not seem to work. Code attached.

ErasableField.java

```
public class ErasableField extends LinearLayout {

    private EditText editText;
    private View button;

    public ErasableField(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(null);
    }

    public ErasableField(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs);
    }

    public ErasableField(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(attrs);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {
        this.setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        editText = (EditText) inflater.
                inflate(R.layout.erasable_field_edittext, this, false);
        button = inflater.inflate(R.layout.erasable_field_button, this, false);

        if (attrs != null) {
            TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ErasableField);

            boolean password = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.ErasableField_password, false);
            if (password) {
                editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
            } else {
                editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            }
        }

        editText.setFocusable(true);
        editText.setClickable(true);
        editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        this.setClickable(false);
        this.setFocusable(false);
        this.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        this.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        this.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.editbox_background);

        addView(editText);
        addView(button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                editText.getText().clear();
            }
        });

        this.addStatesFromChildren();
    }

    public Editable getText() {
        return editText.getText();
    }

    public void setText(CharSequence text) {
        editText.setText(text);
    }

    public void setText(int resId) {
        editText.setText(resId);
    }

    public void setText(char[] text, int start, int len) {
        editText.setText(text, start, len);
    }    
}
```

erasable_field_edittext.xml

```
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@color/grey"
    >

</EditText>
```

erasable_field_button.xml

```
<ImageButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/Button.Delete"
    >

</ImageButton>
```

Nevermind the missing style, it's just a red button with a little cross, it looks like this:

[image]

When the user taps the edittext area, the style should change to a focused style.

I.e. (ignore the different button look ):

[image]

The style I'm trying to use a built in from Android:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/editbox_background_focus_yellow" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/editbox_background_normal" />
</selector>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fixed by changing

```
this.addStatesFromChildren();
```

to

```
this.setAddStatesFromChildren(true);
```

...